# Hashcat with Kali 2 in a VM

Tags: kali-linux, vmware, hashcat

How can I run hashcat using **only** the cpu in a virtual machine?

When I try to run hashcat in my Kali 2 VM I receive the following error:

```
root@kali: hashcat -m 400 -a 0 hash.txt rockyou.txt
hashcat (v3.10) starting...

OpenCL Platform #1: Mesa, skipped! No OpenCL compatible devices found

ERROR: No devices found/left
```

I realize the newer version of hashcat wants to access a video card. This is a Virtual Machine and I'd prefer to use the CPU for these labs.

Version info for Kali:

```
root@kali:~/Desktop/data/target# uname -a
Linux kali 4.6.0-kali1-686 #1 SMP Debian 4.6.4-1kali1 (2016-07-21) i686 GNU/Linux

root@kali:~/Desktop/data/target# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:    kali-rolling
Codename:   kali-rolling
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You must install some stuff. The same happened to me. But you can work with new hashcat 3.x and CPU in your vm, no problem on that:

`apt-get install libhwloc-dev ocl-icd-dev ocl-icd-opencl-dev`

And

`apt-get install pocl-opencl-icd`

This worked for me. I found it [here](http://www.nullsec.us/hashcat-3-0-on-a-32-bit-linux-vm/). What I suggested It's a little different because you can install pocl with apt-get instead of downloading from git like that link suggests... Is the solution worked on my Kali vm.

Comment: Awesome! After an `apt-get upgrade` on 64 bit kali and using the `--force` flag, this worked like a champ! It won't run on 32 bit Kali without a lot of massaging apparently, but at least I have a viable option! [This article](http://www.nullsec.us/hashcat-3-0-on-a-32-bit-linux-vm/) discusses running hashcat in a 32 bit vm but it seemed a bit involved...

Comment: It still works this way with hashcat 6.2

Answer (score 2):

You can use hashcat legacy for that, it's built to run on CPUs rather than GPUs.

https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=frequently_asked_questions

Answer (score 0):

VM has no GPU, therefore hashcat can't work in it. You can either install legacy hashcat as knipp suggested, run it in your host machine or use Kali as a live OS (f.e. USB)

Comment: He is asking to work in vm wih CPU and that is possible without any problem.

Answer (score -3):

Try `hashcat -m 400 -a 0 hash.txt rockyou.txt --force`.